# How to mark all values that are different in table column?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery data-table that displays history records. There are eight different columns with date values.

I would like to set a background color for every value that is different in each column. For example in the first column the first row has `1st Qtr Start Date 03/01/2020`, then second row has `1st Qtr Start Date 03/02/2020`, and the third row has the `1st Qtr Start Date 03/01/2020`.

In that case the second row column that has `1st Qtr Start Date 03/02/2020` should be marked with the red background. I'm not sure what would be the best method to catch the value change inside of the each column. Also, is it possible to do this before the table is initialized? Thank you.

```js
let data = {
  "1": {
    "fiscal_year": 2020,
    "q1_start_9902_susp_dt": "03/01/2020",
    "q2_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q4_end_9902_susp_dt": "04/30/2021",
    "q1_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q4_start_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q2_start_9902_susp_dt": "02/08/2020",
    "q3_start_9902_susp_dt": "07/16/2020",
    "q3_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020"
  },
  "2": {
    "fiscal_year": 2020,
    "q1_start_9902_susp_dt": "03/02/2019",
    "q2_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q4_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q1_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q4_start_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2019",
    "q2_start_9902_susp_dt": "04/30/2019",
    "q3_start_9902_susp_dt": "07/31/2019",
    "q3_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020"
  },
  "3": {
    "fiscal_year": 2020,
    "q1_start_9902_susp_dt": "03/01/2020",
    "q2_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q4_end_9902_susp_dt": "04/30/2021",
    "q1_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q4_start_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q2_start_9902_susp_dt": "02/08/2020",
    "q3_start_9902_susp_dt": "07/16/2020",
    "q3_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020"
  },
  "4": {
    "fiscal_year": 2020,
    "q1_start_9902_susp_dt": "03/02/2019",
    "q2_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q4_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q1_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q4_start_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2019",
    "q2_start_9902_susp_dt": "04/30/2019",
    "q3_start_9902_susp_dt": "07/31/2019",
    "q3_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020"
  },
  "5": {
    "fiscal_year": 2019,
    "q1_start_9902_susp_dt": "01/31/2020",
    "q2_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q4_end_9902_susp_dt": "04/30/2021",
    "q1_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q4_start_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q2_start_9902_susp_dt": "02/08/2020",
    "q3_start_9902_susp_dt": "07/16/2020",
    "q3_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020"
  },
  "6": {
    "fiscal_year": 2019,
    "q1_start_9902_susp_dt": "03/01/2019",
    "q2_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q4_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q1_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q4_start_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2019",
    "q2_start_9902_susp_dt": "04/30/2019",
    "q3_start_9902_susp_dt": "07/31/2019",
    "q3_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020"
  }
};

dialogBox = function(title, message, size) {
  title = title || 'HCS System';
  message = message || 'HCS Dialog Box';
  size = size || 'lg';

  let dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    onEscape: true,
    backdrop: true,
    size: size,
    title: '<strong>' + title + '</strong>',
    message: message
  });
  dialog.prop("id", "dialog-box");
};

$("#history").on("click", function() {
  displayHistory(data);
});

displayHistory = function(data) {
  let $div_reponsive = $('<div class="table-responsive"></div>'),
    $table = $('<table width="100%">').addClass('table table-striped table-bordered').prop("id", "tbl-history"),
    $thead = $('<thead><tr class="bg-custom"><th class="text-center">Fiscal Year</th><th class="text-center">1st Quarter Start</th><th class="text-center">1st Quarter End</th><th class="text-center">2nd Quarter Start</th><th class="text-center">2nd Quarter End</th><th class="text-center">3rd Quarter Start</th><th class="text-center">3rd Quarter End</th><th class="text-center">4th Quarter Start</th><th class="text-center">4th Quarter End</th></tr></thead>'),
    $tbody = $('<tbody>');
    
  if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
    let $tr = $('<tr><td class="text-center" colspan="12">No records were found.</td></tr>');
    $tbody.append($tr);
  } else {
    for (key in data) {
      let $tr = $('<tr>');
      $tbody.prepend($tr);
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].fiscal_year ? data[key].fiscal_year : "N/A").attr("data-order", data[key].fiscal_year).addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q1_start_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q1_start_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q1_end_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q1_end_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q2_start_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q2_start_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q2_end_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q2_end_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q3_start_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q3_start_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q3_end_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q3_end_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q4_start_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q4_start_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q4_end_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q4_end_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
    }
  }

  $div_reponsive.append($table.append([$thead, $tbody]));
  dialogBox('History', $div_reponsive, 'xl');
  $('#tbl-history').DataTable({
    order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    lengthMenu: [
      [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
      [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    pageLength: 5
  });
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="history">Show History</button>
```

Comment: 2 possible approaches come to mind: 1, use a counter to keep track of each value 2. loop and store value in array, then check if value exists in_array(needle, stack)

Comment: And what if all 3 are different? What is your starting point for check? Should 1 row be marked if 2nd and 3ed are the same adn1st is different? Should one be marked if other two are the same, no meter what column?

Comment: @ikiK The first row in the table is start value that we use to compare other rows column values. If first row column is different and third row column is different than the second and third will have background color or a symbol next to the value.

Answer (score 0):

Even after your answer to my comment I am bit confused about your logic and what exactly should be highlighted and under what condition. I made example of if starting point is first row in table cell `1st Qtr Start Date`  to compare it with others.

If this is wrong it would be really useful if you would make a screen shot of your table result from this snippet and highlight the rows that should be marked. I don't quite get it yet. But example below might be starting point:

```
$("#history").on("click", function() {
  displayHistory(data);

  [...document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr')].forEach(tr => { 
      if (document.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').innerHTML !== tr.cells.item(1).innerHTML) {
        tr.cells.item(1).style.color = "red";
      }
    })
});
```

Keep in mind you will have call this also on pagination click also.

```js
let data = {
  "1": {
    "fiscal_year": 2020,
    "q1_start_9902_susp_dt": "03/01/2020",
    "q2_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q4_end_9902_susp_dt": "04/30/2021",
    "q1_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q4_start_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q2_start_9902_susp_dt": "02/08/2020",
    "q3_start_9902_susp_dt": "07/16/2020",
    "q3_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020"
  },
  "2": {
    "fiscal_year": 2020,
    "q1_start_9902_susp_dt": "03/02/2019",
    "q2_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q4_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q1_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q4_start_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2019",
    "q2_start_9902_susp_dt": "04/30/2019",
    "q3_start_9902_susp_dt": "07/31/2019",
    "q3_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020"
  },
  "3": {
    "fiscal_year": 2020,
    "q1_start_9902_susp_dt": "03/01/2020",
    "q2_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q4_end_9902_susp_dt": "04/30/2021",
    "q1_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q4_start_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q2_start_9902_susp_dt": "02/08/2020",
    "q3_start_9902_susp_dt": "07/16/2020",
    "q3_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020"
  },
  "4": {
    "fiscal_year": 2020,
    "q1_start_9902_susp_dt": "03/02/2019",
    "q2_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q4_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q1_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q4_start_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2019",
    "q2_start_9902_susp_dt": "04/30/2019",
    "q3_start_9902_susp_dt": "07/31/2019",
    "q3_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020"
  },
  "5": {
    "fiscal_year": 2019,
    "q1_start_9902_susp_dt": "01/31/2020",
    "q2_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q4_end_9902_susp_dt": "04/30/2021",
    "q1_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q4_start_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020",
    "q2_start_9902_susp_dt": "02/08/2020",
    "q3_start_9902_susp_dt": "07/16/2020",
    "q3_end_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2020"
  },
  "6": {
    "fiscal_year": 2019,
    "q1_start_9902_susp_dt": "03/01/2019",
    "q2_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q4_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q1_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020",
    "q4_start_9902_susp_dt": "12/31/2019",
    "q2_start_9902_susp_dt": "04/30/2019",
    "q3_start_9902_susp_dt": "07/31/2019",
    "q3_end_9902_susp_dt": "09/30/2020"
  }
};

dialogBox = function(title, message, size) {
  title = title || 'HCS System';
  message = message || 'HCS Dialog Box';
  size = size || 'lg';

  let dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    onEscape: true,
    backdrop: true,
    size: size,
    title: '<strong>' + title + '</strong>',
    message: message
  });
  dialog.prop("id", "dialog-box");
};

$("#history").on("click", function() {
  displayHistory(data);

  [...document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr')].forEach(tr => { 
      if (document.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').innerHTML !== tr.cells.item(1).innerHTML) {
        tr.cells.item(1).style.color = "red";
      }
    })
});

displayHistory = function(data) {
  let $div_reponsive = $('<div class="table-responsive"></div>'),
    $table = $('<table width="100%">').addClass('table table-striped table-bordered').prop("id", "tbl-history"),
    $thead = $('<thead><tr class="bg-custom"><th class="text-center">Fiscal Year</th><th class="text-center">1st Quarter Start</th><th class="text-center">1st Quarter End</th><th class="text-center">2nd Quarter Start</th><th class="text-center">2nd Quarter End</th><th class="text-center">3rd Quarter Start</th><th class="text-center">3rd Quarter End</th><th class="text-center">4th Quarter Start</th><th class="text-center">4th Quarter End</th></tr></thead>'),
    $tbody = $('<tbody>');

  if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
    let $tr = $('<tr><td class="text-center" colspan="12">No records were found.</td></tr>');
    $tbody.append($tr);
  } else {
    for (key in data) {
      let $tr = $('<tr>');
      $tbody.prepend($tr);
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].fiscal_year ? data[key].fiscal_year : "N/A").attr("data-order", data[key].fiscal_year).addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q1_start_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q1_start_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q1_end_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q1_end_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q2_start_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q2_start_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q2_end_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q2_end_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q3_start_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q3_start_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q3_end_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q3_end_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q4_start_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q4_start_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
      $tr.append($('<td>').text(data[key].q4_end_9902_susp_dt ? data[key].q4_end_9902_susp_dt : "N/A").addClass('text-center'));
    }
  }

  $div_reponsive.append($table.append([$thead, $tbody]));
  dialogBox('History', $div_reponsive, 'xl');
  $('#tbl-history').DataTable({
    order: [
      [0, "desc"]
    ],
    lengthMenu: [
      [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
      [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    pageLength: 5
  });
};
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  z-index: 9999999
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="history">Show History</button>
```

Let me know if this needs adjustments.